# How to register enumeration output from bash as list in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to register the table names as a variable for future use.
Now I can get all required table names via bash:

```bash
echo $(PGPASSWORD={{ DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD }} psql -U {{ POSTGRES_USER }} -h {{ POSTGRES_HOST }} -d {{ DB_NAME }} -tAc "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'")
```

which gives me output:
`t_book t_author t_version`

Now in Asnible:

```yaml
- name: Server - Get all tables names from the main database {{ DB_NAME }}
  shell: echo $(PGPASSWORD={{ DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD }} psql -U {{ POSTGRES_USER }} -h {{ POSTGRES_HOST }} -d {{ DB_NAME }} -tAc "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'")
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ POSTGRES_USER }}"
  register: main_tables

- name: Server - Display all data from the tables
  shell: echo $(PGPASSWORD={{ DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD }} psql -U {{ POSTGRES_USER }} -h {{ POSTGRES_HOST }} -d {{ DB_NAME }} -tAc "SELECT * FROM {{ item }}")
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ POSTGRES_USER }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ main_tables }}"
```

But I got an error with an unexpected EOF instead of the desired result.
I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Split the attribute *stdout* and iterate the list `loop: "{{ main_tables.stdout.split() }}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you display the registered variable you'll see that the output is in the attribute *stdout*

```yaml
    - shell: echo 't_book t_author t_version'
      register: main_tables
    - debug:
        var: main_tables.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
  main_tables.stdout: t_book t_author t_version
```

Split the string (by default on spaces) and iterate the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Display data from {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ main_tables.stdout.split() }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Display data from t_book
  msg: Display data from t_author
  msg: Display data from t_version
```

Answer (score 0):

You catch this error because of quotes in your statement and variables usage.

To avoid this you can write shell command from the new line ([here is example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#examples)):

```
- name: Server - Get all tables names from the main database {{ DB_NAME }}
  shell: |
    echo $(PGPASSWORD={{ DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD }} psql -U {{ POSTGRES_USER }} -h {{ POSTGRES_HOST }} -d {{ DB_NAME }} -tAc "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'")
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ POSTGRES_USER }}"
  register: main_tables

- name: Server - Display all data from the tables
  shell: |
    echo $(PGPASSWORD={{ DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD }} psql -U {{ POSTGRES_USER }} -h {{ POSTGRES_HOST }} -d {{ DB_NAME }} -tAc "SELECT * FROM {{ item }}")
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ POSTGRES_USER }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ main_tables }}"
```

Or you can wrap your command with another quotes:

```
- name: Server - Display all data from the tables
  shell: 'echo $(PGPASSWORD={{ DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD }} psql -U {{ POSTGRES_USER }} -h {{ POSTGRES_HOST }} -d {{ DB_NAME }} -tAc "SELECT * FROM {{ item }}")'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ POSTGRES_USER }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ main_tables }}"
```

Also, take a look at the [community.postgresql.postgresql_query module – Run PostgreSQL queries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_query_module.html#ansible-collections-community-postgresql-postgresql-query-module) module. Maybe it will do the job you need and make your ansible tasks easier.

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm sure the main problem is related to the `main_tables` variable.I know what I want to do, but I don't know how, that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Could you please post the error? With censored data ofc.

Comment: If the main_tables is string, you probably need [to split it to the list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/split_filter.html) first so you will be able to use it in the with_items correctly. Anyways, error would be helpful to find what exactly goes wrong.